# ngRoute not displaying my views

Tags: html, angularjs, server, gruntjs, ngroute

I'm trying to use ngRoute to route my website to a landing-page and it's not loading any of the html after build and I start my grunt server. I don't get any errors in my console when I try to load up the page either. I can see all of the files being copied into the 'dist folder correctly but when I start my server it takes me to http://localhost:9000 and then just displays an empty index.html page. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I have removed $scope from my config and am still not seeing my landing page. I am able to display $scope variables in my controller when I drop them directly in the body of my index.html file if that helps narrow down the issue.

plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/wagbCGdSx5lRO93u5jCF?p=info

Here is my myWebsite.js

```
/*global angular*/
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myWebsite', ['myWebController', 'ngRoute']);
}(angular));
```

and the controller

```
(function (angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('myWebController', [])
    .controller('myWebController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    }]);
} (angular));
```

and my router

```
/*global angular:true */
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('pageRouter', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$scope', '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($scope, $routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'markup/landing-page.html',
                controller: 'myWebController'
            })
            .when('', {
                templateUrl: 'markup/landing-page.html',
                controller: 'myWebController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                templateUrl: 'markup/landing-page.html',
                controller: 'myWebController'
            });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true});
    }]);
} (angular));
```

heres the index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <base href="/"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myWebsite" ng-controller="myWebController">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/myWebsite.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and finally my gruntfile. I have the 'build' task concatenate all my js files into one and puts it in dist/js/. The markup is copied into dist/markup/ and the index.html file gets copied into dist/. Then I serve up the dist folder on my grunt server.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

var distPath = 'dist/';

grunt.initConfig({

    jshint: {
        files: [ 'src/**/*.js'],
        options: {
            globals: {
                jQuery: true
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        files: ['<%= jshint.files %>'],
        tasks: ['jshint']
    },
    clean: {
        dist: ['dist']
    },
    connect: {
        server: {
            options: {
                keepalive: true,
                port: 9000,
                base: 'dist',
                open: true
            }
        }
    },

    concat: {
        js: {
            src: ['src/main/**/*.js'],
            dest: distPath + '/js/myWebsite.js'
        }
    },
    copy: {
        html: {
            cwd: 'src',
            expand: true,
            src: '*.html',
            dest: distPath + 
        },
        markup: {
            cwd: 'src/main/markup',
            expand: true,
            src: '*.html',
            dest: distPath + '/markup'
        },
        images: {
            cwd: 'src/main/images',
            expand: true,
            src: '*.png',
            dest: distPath + '/images'
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'connect:server']);
grunt.registerTask('devServer', ['build', 'connect:server']);
grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean:dist','jshint', 'concat:js', 'copyDist']);
grunt.registerTask('copyDist', ['copy:html', 'copy:markup', 'copy:images']);
```

};

Comment: Try `.otherwise({redirectTo: 'markup/landing-page.html'});`.

Comment: I added this and I am still seeing a blank page.

Comment: your `ng-view` is blank, that is expected to see a blank page. redirect your `ng-view` to your landing page. in the first controller that handles `ng-view` use `$location.path("/index");`, then in route provider set landing page and new controller. if this works well for you i will post it as an actual answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I am having trouble understanding what you mean. The only controller I have is myWebController. So you're saying to add ng-route to the dependencies, inject $location, then do $location.path("/index") in the controller? I just tried that and it changed my path to "http://localhost:9000/#!/index" in my browser and still is displaying a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

```
You are trying to inject *$scope* in the config function, which is causing the error. 

Below is the snippet after removing $scope.

    angular.module('trial',[]).config((['$scope', '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($scope, $routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    ....
    }));

https://plnkr.co/edit/lgc15G2gadoa5WVYzLH0?p=preview

When you see a blank page, you can open developer tool of the browser and see the console to debug. Make sure you have selected *Show all messages* on the Chrome developer console, which will show you errors
```

I made your version of code work as well. Some of the issues I fixed are described below:

1. Change base URL to be picked up dynamically.

```html
<script>
  document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
</script>
```

2. You were not importing two other script files. I added below entries in your index.html

```html
<script src="myWebController.js"></script>
<script src="pageRouter.js"></script>
```

3. Add *pageRouter* module as a dependency to your main *myWebsite* module.

```js
angular.module('myWebsite', ['myWebController', 'pageRouter']);
```

Working example link: https://plnkr.co/edit/TzkzpJZlfL2XBWV8mUQ9?p=preview

Comment: I removed the $scope from the config function and I am still seeing a blank page. When I open my debug tools in chrome, there are no errors in the console. I am able to see anything that I put directly in the body of the index.html file but the router does not seem to be routing to the landing page.

Comment: Can you create a plunker page or share code on Github so that I can take a look?

Comment: Here is a link to a plunker I made with all of my code in it. https://plnkr.co/edit/wagbCGdSx5lRO93u5jCF?p=info

Comment: Make sure you have selected *Show all messages* on the Chrome developer console, which will show you errors.